# Call to undefined function dl()

Tags: php

I am using PHTML encoder to encode my php file but it is giving error "Call to undefined function dl()" when i run the encoded file.
Somebody please help.

```
<?php
    if(!function_exists("phtmldec")){
        $w=(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=="WIN")?1:0;$ln="phtmlenc".phpversion();$cd=dirname(__FILE__);

        if($w){
            $ln=$ln.".dll";if($cd[1]==":") $cd=substr($cd,2);
        } else {
            $ln=$ln.".so";if(strlen($cd)<3) $cd=getcwd();
        }

        if(version_compare(phpversion(),"5.2.5")==-1){
            $cd1=ini_get('extension_dir');
            $cd2=PHP_EXTENSION_DIR;

            if($cd[strlen($cd)-1]!="/")$cd=$cd."/";

            if($cd1[strlen($cd1)-1]!="/")$cd1=$cd1."/";

            if($cd2[strlen($cd2)-1]!="/")$cd2=$cd2."/";

            if($cd1[1]==":") $cd1=substr($cd1,2);

            if($cd2[1]==":") $cd2=substr($cd2,2);

            $ic=substr_count($cd,"\\")+substr_count($cd,"/");
            $ic1=substr_count($cd1,"\\")+substr_count($cd1,"/");
            $ic2=substr_count($cd2,"\\")+substr_count($cd2,"/");
            $en=str_repeat("../",max($ic,$ic1,$ic2))."..".$cd.$ln;
        } else {
            $en=$ln;$r=dl($en);if(!$r)exit("Unable to load $en");
        }

        $p="F4\$A016YC2@Y(8Q[Y!2F3[@K2.0>K0Z%5^#2\\,&;5L7\$<KHL)BH<`";
        phtmldec($p);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `dl` is disabled by default since 5.3

Comment: I just tidied your code, and you had an starting curly brace { missing (just after the last else) and a enclosing curly brace } missing at the end of the code.

Comment: @aleation But is is still giving the same error.

Comment: @k102 so how can i use PHTML encoder for php having version higher than 5.3

Answer (score 3):

as @k102 mentioned `dl()` has been disabled by default since 5.3:

as refered on the php documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

```
    5.3.0   dl() is now disabled in some SAPIs due to stability issues.
The only SAPIs that allow dl() are CLI and Embed. Use the Extension Loading Directives instead.
```

as suggested there, use the Extension Loading Directives instead:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension

---

Basically your only choices are:

1. Load the extension configuring it properly on the php.ini
2. Use one of the mentioned SAPI's that still supports `dl()` as mentioned in the documentation:
   (CLI, CGI and Embed)
3. Downgrade your php version if you really need to load it dinamically

Comment: I used 'dl(php_curl)' (dinamyc load) to enable php_curl when using `php -f file.php` method (CLI as mentioned) and was faster than edit original php.ini and than create a new once php.ini then load it with `-c /path/php.ini`. Because CLI passes filename as $argv[0], just need to check for non-emtpy $argv with `if(@!empty($argv)) dl('php_curl');` to load it.

Comment: Are there any alterntives to load php extensions at runtime ? e.g. when you have no controll over the php ini on hosted servers ?