# "Call to undefined function dl()" despite enable_dl

Tags: php, wamp

Since my client's dedicated server is slow to access, I've decided to work on the project on my local WAMP server.

I'm using the same PHP version as he has on his server, but even when `enable_dl` is on it still gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in C:\wamp\www\dane\login.php on line 2
```

After searching, I realized that `dl()` has been disabled since PHP 5.3.0.

But I somehow need to make it work so I can keep going. Any help appreciated.

BTW, this script is using sourceguardian

Comment: Doesn't a `ini_set("extension", $extension_name);` do it?

Comment: How do I do it? I'm sorry, I have no knowledge about the PHP extentions

Comment: Replace `dl(` with `ini_set("extension", `.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function dl()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163525/call-to-undefined-function-dl)